# На каком типе серверов можно запускать Python скрипты

Tags: python, веб-программирование, сокет

я давно изучаю python, но вот постигла меня такая проблема...

Я писал программу консольный чат (Клиент-серверный), пишу с помощью модуля `socket`.
Всё написал и тут вспомнил что клиент с другого компьютера не сможет подключится к моему приложению ибо у меня только серый ip. Я знаю что белые щяс стоят не дорого но всё-же хотелось бы залить программу-сервер на сервер чтобы она постоянно работала. Кто либо может подсказать какой тип серверов для этого используется и вообще как это провернуть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно, конечно, взять выделенный сервер, но если нагрузка не велика, то вполне хватит VDS. Например от [Hetzner](https://www.hetzner.com/cloud-ru). Подойдёт даже CX11 за 2,99. Там и IP сразу "белый" будет.

Comment: Спасибо всем! Я очень долго искал ответ на этот вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Ищите любой хостинг VPS/VDS хостинг. Это по сути выделенная лично вам виртуальная машина с белым ip(тут могу ошибиться), которую вы сами настраиваете, как свою личную.
На нем вы можете установить любую операционную систему(из тех, которые предлгает хостинг). Устанавливаете на этой машине всё что вам хочется, и администрируете её как вам хочеться. Тарифы и условия у всех разные. 
Но т.к. вам, по всей видимости, не требуется больших мощностей, можете выбрать любой.